# .effect('highlight') a little overzealous

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

My code is available below and here: http://jsfiddle.net/CPLMu/51/

```
$timer = $('<input/>')
    .after($('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-clock"></span>'))
    .appendTo('div')
    .effect('highlight', {color: 'green'}, 1000);
```

The problem is that, although I asked only `$timer` to `.effect('highlight')`, for some reason the `<span>` element (here, an icon) is also highlighted!

What is the problem? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you only want the input to be highlighted, try this:

```
$timer = $('<input/>').effect('highlight', {color: 'green'}, 1000)
.after($('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-clock"></span>'))
.appendTo('div');
```

By putting the `effect` on the end of the chain you were highlighting the span since it is returned from the `after` function.

Comment: I thoughy `.after()` returned the original object! What is the corresponding function that returns only the original object?

Answer (score 2):

like this? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CPLMu/52/)

```
$timer = $('<input/>')
    .appendTo('div')
    .effect('highlight', {color: 'green'}, 1000);

$('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-clock"></span>')
    .appendTo('div');
```

I think you should separate the icon from the input ... at least in code, as the highlight effect will highlight all items in chain.

Comment: you just chained again all items ... with that it's same thing you did in 1'st place ...